# LInq query return value specific field

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 tables as follows :

**CatTable**

- CatCode
- CatName

**DogTable**

- DogCode
- CatCode
- NameCode

So I would like to write down a query where return me the list of all data present in the table **CatTable**
PLUS if in the Table **DogTable** the value in the field “**CatCode**” is the same of  **CatTable.CatCode**  and the field “**NameCode**” is Empty then should return a value "*false*" in the field “**DogTable.CatCode**”

Example

```
var query = from c in CatTable 
            from d in DogTable
            where c.CatCode == d.CatCode 
            select new { c.CatCode, c.CatName, d.CatCode }
```

Do you have any suggestion about that?

Comment: What have you tried? The dog/cat example isn't particularly helpful for understanding your use case.`then should return a value "false" in the field “DogTable.CatCode”` Based on your earlier description, `CatCode` is not a boolean, so what you're asking here doesn't make sense. Even if you mean the string "false", that's just a bad approach to begin with (and has all the hallmarks of either an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), or a stringly typed approach.).

Comment: try something like: `new { CatCode = c.CatCode == d.CatCode && (d.NameCode == null || d.NameCode == "") }`, you will get a bool property called `CatCode` and you can select the other properties you want as you already have done. That's the best I can offer with the limited knowledge, it's not 100% clear what you want and it doesn't help not knowing the data types you are working with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple version is to use the `Any` to return the boolean of the logic you want on that last field

```
var query = CatTable.Select(ct => new 
{ 
    CatCode = ct.CatCode, 
    CatName = ct.CatName, 
    DogCatCode = !DogTable.Any(dt => dt.CatCode == ct.CatCode && dt.NameCode == "")
});
```